# Invalid URI: the Format of the URI could not be determined with web reference

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wsdl

Any help appreciated.

The error message reads:

> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind) at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.set_Url(String value) at WebApplication1.Chase.pconWSService.set_Url(String Value) in \Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Web References\Chase\Reference.vb:line 102 at WebApplication1.Chase.pconWSService..ctor() in \Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Web References\Chase\Reference.vb:line 83

But is this referring to the web reference (wsdl)? And why 2 different locations?

The wsdl was given to me by the vendor, anyway here is my code, it's short:

```
Protected Sub transfer()
Try        
    Dim objXMLHTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60()
    Dim service As New Chase.pconWSService ' The error is thrown here
```

Comment: I believe this is caused by my webconfig file, specifically this line: <WebApplication1.My.MySettings>
             
               <setting name="WebApplication1_Chase_pconWSService" serializeAs="String">
                   <value>/pconWS/9_5/</value>
               </setting>
           </WebApplication1.My.MySettings>

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my web config was not pointed at the actual web service (host) but at my local machine.  Once I repointed it the thing worked.